# bat file seemingly ignoring pause statements

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm setting up a bat file to unattendedly remove local user profiles, but for some reason it keeps closing, skipping the pause command.

My .bat is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF & CLS & ECHO.

REM Control admin rights.
REM NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO Dit bestand moet met administrator-rechten worden utgevoerd. 
REM ECHO Druk op een toets om dit venster te sluiten. & ECHO. & PAUSE >NUL & EXIT /D)

REM After confirmation of admin rights.
CALL DelProf2.exe /L
PAUSE

REM Reboot when finished.
ECHO SHUTDOWN /R /T 0
PAUSE
```

I'm aware this isn't quite unattended yet (in case you're curious about the DelProf2.exe, see [here](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/#syntax-and-examples)) but that's because it's still in testing.

I'm confirming that the user is running my script with admin rights, then I'd like to list the user profiles (using the L switch fom delprof) and then I'd like to simulate a reboot command using ECHO. My window should ask for confirmation twice, given the 2 pause statements in the .bat.

Yet when I run the bat as administrator, the screen only flashes quickly, and disappears. What am I missing here?

Comment: `Pause` does not ask for confirmation but rather any kind of keyboard input. How do you run this batch?

Comment: I'm running the batch by right clicking the bat file and selecting 'run as administrator'. The DelProf2.exe is located in the same directory as the bat.

Comment: Did you try to start a `cmd` as an administrator and run the batch from there? That way you would catch any error message you might miss if it's closing right after starting it.

Comment: Huh, seems I'm getting an error running the .exe now. I'll revisit that and check back.

Comment: I've figured it out! It works fine if I run the .bat file locally. It doesn't work when running it from a network share, seems that's the issue here.. Windows doesn't recognise UNC paths, I'll try to rework that.

Answer (score 0):

The .bat file itself wasn't faulty in this case. It's that I'm trying to run it in a network share and windows dosen't support UNC paths. I'm going to try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013941/how-to-run-batch-file-from-network-share-without-unc-path-are-not-supported-me).